# Using codeigniter, I have a webpage and several links inside that page, whats the best way to code that in the controller so its not a mess

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have a webpage which contains several links to other pages in the body. Currently, I'm coding each href inside a page like this:

```
<href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>Home/tikidology'>
```

And that calls a function in the controller:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller{
function tikidology(){
$this->load->view('pages/tikidology');}}
```

So my controller page is getting full of these one line functions. is there a way I can put all my links that are on one page inside one function in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

The CodeIgniter "[Static Pages](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html)" tutorial shows one possible way to do what you want.

In short, it demonstrates a `view` function that takes an argument. The argument is used to "select" the correct view.

The no-frills version might look like this.

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{    
    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page);
    }
}
```

The doc tutorial shows some other code you should consider adding.

To use the above, the link to Tickidology would be `https://example.com/home/view/tickidology` making the value of `$page` equal to `'tickidology'`. You can use routing to eliminate the need to include 'view/' in the URI if you like.

The default value of `$page` is 'home' which may or may not be relevant to your site. The idea is that if `Home::view()` is called without an argument there is still a (default) view to be loaded.

While not part of the answer, I suggest you use the URL Helper function `anchor()` ([doc here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#anchor)) to create your links, e.g.

```
echo anchor('home/view/tikidology', 'Tickidology');
```

BTW, when using `base_url()` the URI segments can (should be) used as an argument to the function, e.g.

```
<href = '<?php echo base_url('home/view/tikidology'); ?>'>Tikidology</a>
```